# default menu theme is black text on grey after long series of upgrades

Tags: upgrade, 14.10, themes

This laptop that I've got has been upgraded over an extremely long period of time from 11.04, 11.10, 12.04, 12.10, 13.10, 14.04, 14.10.  I think I've got almost all of it working again, at least portably, except for one problem that has been utterly annoying me, which came up only in the most recent upgrade to 14.10:

All of my menus are the default dark-ish grey color, with black text.
Today, I checked out the theme selector, and the other three themes do not have that problem, but the default one does.  As the default one is the only one that doesn't have significant other problems, how can I go about fixing that?